# getcontext().prec not working as expected

Tags: python, decimal, precision

```py
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 8
print(getcontext(),"\n")

x_amount = Decimal(0.025)
y_amount = Decimal(0.005)

test3 = x_amount - y_amount

print("test3",test3)
```

**Output:**

```
Context(prec=8, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999, Emax=999999, capitals=1, clamp=0, flags=[], traps=[InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero, Overflow]) 


test3 0.020000000
```

Why does this return value of 'test3' up to 9 decimal places if the precision is set to 8 according to example mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)?

And it changes to 3 decimal places if I replace Line 6 and 7 in the above code with:

```py
x_amount = Decimal('0.025')
y_amount = Decimal('0.005')
```

I am using decimals in a financial application and find it very confusing about conversions, operations, definition, precision etc. Is there a link which I can refer to know the details of using decimals in python?

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but using `float` to initialize `Decimal` is always wrong. Never initialize a `Decimal` from a `float`; it just reproduces the inaccuracy of `float` in the `Decimal`. Passing a `str` is the only safe way to do this. When I do this with `str`, and use strings that are more precise than the `prec`, the initial values are more precise, but all math operations are producing the expected level of precision (e.g. `Decimal("0.025") + Decimal("0.123456789")` gets `Decimal('0.14845679')`, which has exactly eight places of precision.

Comment: In case of `Decimal('0.025') - Decimal('0.005')` there is no need to add up to 8 zeroes at the end, because you get the exact result. The decimal initialized with the float 0.025 is `Decimal('0.0025000000000000000520417042793042128323577344417572021484375')`, though, so the result gets cut off. This doesn't explain why you get 9 decimal places instead of 8, though. It seems, it starts counting from the first non-zero place, but this is just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is correct. `prec` says how many digits to keep *starting from the most significant non-zero digit*. So in your result:

```
test3 0.020000000
         ^^^^^^^^
```

the digits pointed to by carets are the expected eight digits covered by the precision. The reason you get all of them is that using `float` to initialize `Decimal` is always wrong. Never initialize a `Decimal` from a `float`; it just reproduces the inaccuracy of `float` in the `Decimal` (try `print`ing `x_value` and `y_value` to see the garbage). Passing a `str` is the only safe way to do this.

When you do this with `str`, the individual `Decimal`s "know" the last digit of meaningful precision they possess, and it only goes to the third decimal place, so the result doesn't include precision beyond that point. If you want `prec` capping to kick in, try initializing one of the arguments with more precision than `prec`, and the result will be rounded to `prec`.